# convert c++ header file to protobuf .proto file

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am wondering, is there any tool that I can use to convert a .h file into a .proto file for c++?
What I want to do is: I have several structs into a .h file, and I want to serialize them and send them via protbuf. To do that, I need a .proto file to generate the .pb.h and .pb.cc files and then I will be able serialize the structs and send them.

Does anybody know if there is such a tool? I could do it manually but I will take much time because the header file contains many structs.

Thank you!

I am editing my question to let you know that I haven't found what I was asking for, but I found this https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/wiki/ProtoGen tool which was also very helpful. You give as parameter the .proto file and it generates the c# code. Hope it helps!

Comment: https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c this may help!

Comment: You need to go the other way around. Create a proto file and use `protoc` to build the C++ structs.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to do. To build a .proto file and use protoc to build the c++ structs. But I already have the structs in a header file and I am wondering if there is any way to convert this file to a .proto file so I can get the proper c++ structs that can be used from protobuf.

Comment: @Blackhat002 Thank you for your response. However, the protobuf-c, only does what protoc does. It generates the .pb.h and .pb.cc after you give it a .proto file :)

Comment: I'm not aware of any such tool, and if it existed it would probably require pretty strict syntax in the header to be converted. I'm not sure it would be generically useful.

Comment: You could try searching and replacing struct with message and ',' with ';' and so on. However you will need some manual polishing...

Comment: You could probably get something like this to work using libclang. But I think the payoff wouldn't justify the expense for a single project.

Comment: I hear LLVM can parse C++ syntax and embed to compiler, would the LLVM help?

Comment: I'm (also) not aware of such a tool - the main problem is that the proto file gives the abstract structure (ensure names are unique and so on) and t he .h/.cc only a possible implementation of the described structure. I would try using a good editor (like sublimetext) with multi line edit and then create the proto by hand.

Comment: I don't see how it's even possible to create a proto file from a header file, which is missing required information, i.e. required, optional, repeated keywords.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script that will do a good job using [libclang](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/tree/master/bindings/python) Python bindings.

First, generate a [compile_commands.json](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html) using CMake for your project. Parse the complete compiler command line for your code of interest.

Second, pass the compile command line to libclang from your Python script to parse a compilation unit, that contains your header of interest.

Third, iterate the AST and extract your structs of interest.

Fourth, generate protobuf from the isolated AST sub-trees.

This is just a sketch, but I did something similar to recursively find all headers included in a compilation unit.

Answer (score 0):

Following code  maybe help:

```py
for line in open("frame.v2.pb.h"):
    if (line.startswith("class") and line.find("::google::protobuf::Message") > 0 ) \
            or (line.startswith("  //") and line.find("@@protoc_insertion_point") < 0 and
                    line.find("--------")<0 ) \
            or line.startswith("namespace ") \
            :
        print(line.strip())
```